# Internet Explorer AutoIT object and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, internet-explorer, object, character-encoding, autoit

I'm creating an IE navigation in my AutoIT script:

```
$oIE = ObjCreate("Shell.Explorer.2")
GUICtrlCreateObj($oIE, 10, 80, 600, 480)
$oIE.navigate("http://myurl.com/raw.php")
```

It is working fine, but it does not display the UTF-8 characters.

Fe. I see `Ä™` instead of `ę`, `ĹĽ` instead of `ż`, etc...

I was tryin to set this on my raw.php file using:

```
header('Content-Language: pl');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't help. Default Internet Explorer object encoding still doesn't support UTF-8.

Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is on the server side. Internet explorer object has no problem with any encoding.